# What is the difference between the two fields on the bottom half of the upper ECAM display on Airbus airplanes?

Tags: flight-instruments, emergency-procedures, airbus, display

[image]

Note the two fields with green text on the bottom half of the display, separated by a white line. During abnormal conditions, the left portion may show "ECAM actions," but I do not know what the logic behind the right portion is when it shows, for example, "LAND ASAP." Not sure what the logic is during normal conditions, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two fields at the bottom are explained in the A320 FCOM as follows:

> The lower part, which is dedicated to ECAM messages, is divided into
> two parts of several lines each.
>
> Left part:
>
> - Primary or independent warnings and cautions, or
> - Memo information
>
> Right part:
>
> - Title of system affected by a primary or independent warning or caution in case of overflow on the left part, or
> - Secondary failure, or
> - Memo, or
> - Special lines (such as "AP OFF", "LAND ASAP")

<sup>([Airbus A320 FCOM - Indicating and Recording Systems](https://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Indicating_and_Recording_Systems.html) - ECAM Description - Indications on E/WD)</sup>

The picture you show contains only **memos** both on the left and the right:

> Memos appear in the lower part of the E/WD. They are normally in green, but may be
> amber in abnormal situtations.
> Memos list functions or systems that are temporarily used in normal operations.
> Each chapter of the "Warning and Cautions" section of this manual lists memo messages.

The FCOM shows several other examples:

1. **Independent Failure**

   > [image: ECAM Independent Failure]
   >
   > If there are too many ECAM messages for the amount of space available in the lower part
   > of the E/WD, a green arrow appears at the bottom of the display, pointing down to show
   > that the information has overflowed off the screen. The pilot can scroll down to view
   > additional messages by pushing the CLR pushbutton on the ECAM control panel (on the
   > pedestal, just below the lower ECAM DU).
2. **Primary and Secondary Failure**

   > [image: ECAM Primary and Secondary Failure]
   >
   > The ECAM DU displays a primary failure as a boxed title.
   > It identifies a secondary failure by putting a star in front of the title of the affected system.
   >
   > *Note:* The DU displays the overflow symbol, if primary or secondary failures overflow. In
   > case of ELEC EMER CONFIG, the secondary failures are inhibited.
3. **TO and LDG Memos**

   > During the takeoff and landing phases, the right side of the memo area displays specific T.O.
   > INHIBIT or LDG INHIBIT (magenta) memos.
   > Takeoff and landing memos are displayed, as follows, during the related flight phases:
   >
   > [image: ECAM T.O. Memo]
   >
   > * This line disappears when the test is completed. It is replaced by "TO CONFIG
   > NORMAL", if aircraft configuration is correct.
   > The test is requested again, if the configuration becomes abnormal.

Comment: So, the "no smoking" and "seat belts" text in the image refer to TO memos being completed? Also, what does the text on the right field refer to (as it is not an overflow or secondary failure)?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson No, the TO memos are special, they always look like in the picture from the FCOM. Your picture shows *regular* memos, not related to TO or LDG. I'm not sure why some memos are shown on the left and some on the right. The FCOM does not say...